# SQL joined columns data transposed into grid of totals

Tags: sql, join, transpose

I have two columns of data populated from separate tables:

```
KS2    Result
4a     C
4a     C
3c     C+
3c     C-
5a     B
5a     B
5a     B
5a     C+
```

I would like to transpose this into a grid of totals eg:

```
      C-    C    C+    B
3c    1     -    1     -
4a    -     2    -     -
5a    -     -    1     3
```

(- represents NULL)

The SQL I'm using to populate the columns is:

```
select ks2en, result 
    from student 
        join subject on subject.upn=student.upn 
            where name='English'
```

Is there an efficient way of doing this maybe using something like a group by?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can group by ks2en column and use CASE to separately count the result.

```
select ks2en, 
       count(case result when 'C-' then 1 end),
       count(case result when 'C' then 1 end),
       count(case result when 'C+' then 1 end),
       count(case result when 'B' then 1 end),
  from student join subject 
    on subject.upn=student.upn 
 where name='English'
 group by ks2en;
```

Output:

```
ks2en   C-    C    C+    B
--------------------------
3c      1     0    1     0
4a      0     2    0     0
5a      0     0    1     3
```

Note that this will give you 0 instead of null, when there are no applicable grades.